# Twofish encryption implementation using python

Tags: python, twofish

I'm trying to encrypt "Hello world" using Twofish algorithm in python. I use this package https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twofish/0.3.0

There's no problem encrypting the message, however I want to set cipher mode to CBC and I don't know how to do it. There's no explanation about how to set cipher mode in document and I can't find the answer when I search in google.

So, have anyone used this package before? and how could you set the cipher mode? please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This library does not enable you to choose a cypher mode. It is based on [libtowfish](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/libtwofish-dev/libtwofish.3.en.html), and the documentation of the library states (emphahsis is mine) :

> void Twofish_encrypt(Twofish_key *xkey, Twofish_Byte plain[16],
>   Twofish_Byte crypto[16]);
>
> Encrypt a single block of data.
>
> This function encrypts a single block of 16 bytes of data. If you want
>   to encrypt a larger or variable-length message, you will have to use a
>   cipher mode, such as CBC or CTR. **These are outside the scope of this
>   implementation.**

You will need to implement modes yourself (if this is for a serious application, you probably should not), or find a library that does it for you. As far as I know, the main crypto libraries in Python ([PyCryptodome](https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/index.html), [Cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/)) does not have twofish implemented.